# Ajax jQuery load in 9 divs at a time

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html

I'm having a div that looks like this:

```
<div class="all_articles third_article_module">
    <!--load in content from loadmore.html via ajax -->
</div>
```

I also have a show me more text that looks like this:

```
<div class="showmemore">
    <h2>Load more articles</h2>
</div>
```

My loadmore.html page loops through and show all articles. The ting I want to do is only show a number of articles each time (for example 9) and then the h2 tag appends to the end of the div. When there's no more articles left I want the h2 tag to be hidden. My JS looks like this:

```
$('.showmemore_inner h2').on("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.third_article_module').load('loadmore.html');
});

$(document).ajaxStart(function(){
    $(show_header).text('Loading more articles').css('color', '#4c4c4e');
    $('.showmemore .showmemore_inner h2 span').css('display', 'block');
});

$(document).ajaxComplete(function(){
    $('.showmemore').appendTo('.all_articles.third_article_module');
    $('.ajax_article').addClass('active');
    $(show_header).text('Load more articles');
});
```

In my loadmore.html I have a div container and the content each wrapped in a div that's called .ajax_article.

Comment: I don't understand your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You should add a parameter to loadmore.html to tell how many articles you need and where to start. like this:

```
var start = 0;
$('.showmemore_inner h2').on("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.third_article_module').load('loadmore.html?articles=9&start=' + start,'',function(data) {if(!data) {$('.showmemore_inner h2').remove();}});
    start = start + 9;
});
```

This will ensure that each time show more is clicked, next 9 articles will be fetched, and if no data is received show more will be removed. Of course in loadmore.html you should loop only those articles that are requested by parameters.

Comment: is loadmore.html dynamic or static?

Comment: is it? or you want it to be? sorry but I assumed you have a dynamic loadmore.html or at least could code one, which could change its contents according to parameters sent via url. if not and you don't know how, I suggest you look into that problem first.